# way to compare whats going on during a specific time?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, timer

So I have multiple timers going on at a given time, is there any way to say,

```
if (randomTimer isGoingOnAtTheSameTimeAs randomTimer2)
[self doSomethingAwesome];
```

any responses would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are those `NSTimer`s? If so, [`isValid`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDDGAGA) tells you if a timer is running.

Comment: @ownageGuy, next time, please understand that drug related content, no matter what purpose it serves (humorous or otherwise), is most likely not appropriate for SO.

Comment: @Coda: I'd guess that was intended to be short for "method", not "methamphetamine".

Comment: @JoshCaswell Best to be safe, eh?  Besides, he needed a little code formatting.

Comment: @CodaFi: /me shrugs Code formatting is always helpful.

Comment: I don't know why people seem to be downvoting you tonight, but don't let it get you down.  People downvote for no good reason.  Just keep your head up and ask good questions.  It also doesn't hurt to answer a few!

Comment: It would indeed be helpful to make a mandatory downvote reasoning field or at least categorize it ala close question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([randomTimer isValid] && [randomTimer2 isValid]) {
    [self doSomethingAwesome];
}
```